# Why does `advertising_id` Flutter package give advertising ID that contains all zeros?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-advertising-id

I am trying to get Google Advertising ID with Flutter in Android. I added `advertising_id` package to my project and used exactly the same code as example of this package contains:

```
String? advertisingId = await AdvertisingId.id(true);
```

But when I debug this code in Android Studio, it returns `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` always. I added following line to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

But it changed nothing.

Why does advertising ID is zeroed always? Is there any way to get it in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear, did you placed your adver. id ?

```
///do you use id here?
 String? _advertisingId = '**here your id**';
  bool? _isLimitAdTrackingEnabled;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  initPlatformState() async {
    String? advertisingId;
    bool? isLimitAdTrackingEnabled;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      advertisingId = await AdvertisingId.id(true);
    } on PlatformException {
      advertisingId = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    try {
      isLimitAdTrackingEnabled = await AdvertisingId.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled;
    } on PlatformException {
      isLimitAdTrackingEnabled = false;
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _advertisingId = advertisingId;
      _isLimitAdTrackingEnabled = isLimitAdTrackingEnabled;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. You say I have to place my advertising ID somewhere? But advertising ID is what I am trying to get. I don't know it; Google assigns it.

Comment: it will work in your release build. did you try release build?

Comment: No, I didn't. It is not documented in Google, is it just expected behavior that in debug build the ads ID is zeroed out always?

Comment: I just test once. in debug mode it show 00.. but in release mode it works fine. you can try a release build.